# Powershell variable passing inline

Tags: powershell, inline, powershell-cmdlet

```
get-content C:\OUlist.txt | get-qadcomputer -SearchRoot $_ -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties info
```

In the OUlist.txt file there is a list of OUs.  I am having trouble passing each of the OUs to the get-qadcomputer command.  If I hard code the OU in the command using 'company.com\workstation\Win7' instead of the "$_" the script runs fine.

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly to with regard to passing the OU down the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -SearchRoot parameter does not accept pipeline input, so you'll need to use a loop:

```
get-content C:\OUlist.txt | ForEach-Object { get-qadcomputer -SearchRoot $_ -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties info }
```

Comment: This indeed was the issue, resolved and working now.  Obvious when I look at the situation now, there was just too many trees in the way for me to see the forest.  Thank you for your vision.